# Prove that $\mathscr{T}$ is the discrete topology on $X$ if and only if $X$ is a finite set.

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a set and let $\mathscr{T}$ be the finite complement topology on $X$. Prove that $\mathscr{T}$ is the discrete topology on $X$ if and only if $X$ is a finite set.

*def*: $\mathscr{T}=\mathscr{P}(X)$ is called the discrete topology on $X$.

Comment: What part are you having trouble with?

Comment: This is almost trivial and follows from the definitions. What exactly are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X=\{x_1,,x_2,...,x_m\}$

Then for $x \in X$ we have that $\{x\}^c$ is finite thus $\{x\}$ belongs to the topology.

So $X$ has the discrete topology.

If $X$ is infinite then exists an infinite $E \subseteq X$ such that $E^c$ is infinite.

But since $\mathcal{J}$ is the finite complement topology,we have that $E \neq \mathcal {J}$

This is a contradiction since $\mathcal {J}$ is also the discrete topology by hypothesis.